# Why StringUtils Apache class is not recognized in Android?

Tags: android

Why **import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils** cannot be imported in android by default.

Do i have to include an external library? Then where can i find that library on the web?

```
package com.myapps.urlencoding;

import android.app.Activity;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class EncodeIdUtil extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     private static Long multiplier=Long.parseLong("1zzzz",36);

        /**
         * Encodes the id.
         * @param id the id to encode
         * @return encoded string
         */
        public static String encode(Long id) {
            return StringUtils.reverse(Long.toString((id*multiplier), 35));
        }

        /**
         * Decodes the encoded id.
         * @param encodedId the encodedId to decode
         * @return the Id
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException if encodedId is not a validly encoded id.
         */
        public static Long decode(String encodedId) 
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
            long product;
            try {
                product = Long.parseLong(StringUtils.reverse(encodedId), 35);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            if ( 0 != product % multiplier || product < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            return product/multiplier;
        }
}
```

Comment: Is it this the site where i have to download the required API:
http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache Commons lang is a separate library. You can find it [here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

Comment: I have it downloaded already. The downloaded folder does not have any jar file that i can include in my android project. What to do now?

Comment: The jar files are inside this zip file: http://apache.mogo.be/commons/lang/binaries/commons-lang-2.5-bin.zip

Comment: Ok! Downloaded and ran the code but i'm getting null pointer exception
when i call the encode method in my main activity?

Comment: @Maxood I think that would be an unrelated problem to this question. Without looking at your main method I can't say what might be the issue. Are you sure you fill in the `id` value? Perhaps ask another question about this specific problem if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Here is my main activity:

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        long var = 70;
        
        
        
        Long multiplier=Long.parseLong("1zzzz",36);
        
          EncodeIdUtil edUtil = new EncodeIdUtil();
          //Null pointer exception
          edUtil.encode(var);
        
          
    }
}

Comment: You are possibly getting the null pointer exception because you don't package it with the application, to do this go configure build path then order and export, then click the checkbox next to the jar file you want

Answer (score 34):

You don't say whether you are using Eclipse or Android Studio. In Android Studio, you would add,

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
```

to your source code file. In build.gradle, you need to change your dependency from something like,

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile  'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
}
```

In other words, you would add to the dependency.

Comment: Don't use this lib. By using this lib, While uploading apk to Google play store, It will show 0 supported devices. Instead use compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'. it works.

Answer (score 13):

Android offers a subset of that functionality in [android.text.TextUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html).

Depending on what you need from StringUtils, that might be an option. E.g., it has join, split.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Android Studio try to use workflow provided to add dependencies rather than manually adding the downloaded library or manually changing gradle files.

1. File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> app -> Dependencies Tab
2. Click '+' in the bottom left corner and select "Library dependency"
3. In the search field type: "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3" and click Search
4. Select "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

just add following dependency in module level gradle file(build.gradle)

```
implementation  'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7'
```