# Android dev notepad tutorial exercise, annoying empty notes

Tags: android

Hi there I have been doing the notepad exercise and it has a really annoying problem which was fine and I was able to correct it up until exercise 3 which it now doesnt work!
My problem is that currently it will allow empty inputs to create a note, really annoying. 
I was able to fix it using the

```
String taskName = mTitleText.getText().toString();
if (taskName.equals("")) {finish();}
else {addNote();}
```

method but when the full tutorial is completed the method doesnt work anymore. I have tried all sorts of ways of calling it but it still wont do anything, it just posts an empty note. It does register that it is empty but posts it anyway.
Does anyone know how to fix this??

Thanks for your help 
Kris

Comment: Post full code you have with comments in it what is not working. That will help you in getting valid answers.

Comment: The solution to Notepad exercise #3 features a `saveState` method which is responsible for saving/updating the note in the database. There is no `addNote` method, which I suppose you added in your solution. But `saveState` is called from different places, e.g. `onPause`. One possible reason why your workaround does not work is that `onPause` et similia in your solution are now calling your `addNote` method instead of `saveState`, thus bypassing the empty note guard.

Comment: thats it!! thanks i totaly overlooked that. ur the man!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
```

then

```
StringUtils.isBlank(taskName);
```

you'll probably have to add the library go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808733/why-strinutils-apache-class-is-not-recognized-in-android) for help.

Comment: Why use Apache `StringUtils` when `TextUtils` and its `isEmpty` method seems to perform the same task and is included in the Android standard library?

Answer (score 0):

the String.isEmpty() function should suffice for this - Check out your Java docs

Comment: Thats what i thought but it doesnt appear to work with this code. infact when using eclipse the isEmpty() isnt even there and comes up as an error!

Comment: so do you have if(taskName.isEmpty()) {finish();}
else {addNote();}, It also depends on what mTitleText.getText().toString(); is returning may be worth debugging it and seeing exactly what this string is being printed as there is no reason this shouldnt work.

Comment: yeah with taskName being defined using String taskName = mTitleText.getText().toString();

Comment: can you print the mTitleText.getText().toString(); and see what its returning ?

Comment: mTitleText is just calling an EditText field, mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.EditText_taskName); it checking it to see if anything is in it hense the .getText().toString() and up until exercise 3 it was working fine. i also have textwatcher making sure if anything is changed and the cancel button is hit then it will bring up a dialog box. should i maybe try and hook the textwatcher instead and see if that works?

Comment: You can try but this should be working, perhaps clean and build your code again perhaps Android hasnt regenerated ID's correctly! Maybe someone else can help as this method is working for me might be something elsewhere in your code. Sorry

Comment: when changing the code to a Toast to make sure that it is seeing that it is an empty field it returns correctly but when returning to main page it will still add empty note. mauybe it has something to do with the populatefields()??