# Why firebaseuser.getdisplay name is returning something even it doesn't contain a name?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, onstart

Here is my onStart method I want to open an activity when user has updated his profile name

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (firebaseUser != null) {
        if (firebaseUser.getDisplayName() == null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(WorkerMaps.this, FirstWorkerInformation.class));
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Although, it says name is not null as you're already checking `FirebaseUser` for null and thus, the default null-checking mechanism perceives it like if `FirebaseUser` is not null, it's entities won't be null too but that't not the actual case because many a time, `DisplayName()` return null too. So, ignore that suggestion, that's how the default mechanism works.

Comment: I replace the if (firebaseUser!=null), still it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry sir I can't ignore that as my interface depends upon whether the user has provided his name or not

Comment: What doesn't work? You didn't have to replace anything, it was perfectly fine, just ignore that warning/suggestion.

Comment: By ignoring, I meant that you've to ignore that suggestion which says `(if getCurrentUser.getDisplayname != null)  is always true`. Leave that null check there as it is, Null cheking is very important.

Comment: No, actually there is no suggestion, the case is when i update my display name it returns me the name all good till now but when there is no display name still it's returning some values like " " (a space).

Comment: Please help it's like my nightmare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, nowhere in the question have you mentioned your actual problem.

Hence, what your problem is that even if the displayName() doesn't contain a name, it still returns something which is not null.

Hence, what you can do for that is modify your code and use `isBlank()` as this.

`if (firebaseUser.getDisplayName() == null || firebaseUser.getDisplayName().isBlank()) {`

Now, what this will do that it will also check if your `displayName` only containts spaces and no characters and if true, it will enter in your `if` scope.

You can read more about `isBlank()` [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/java11/check-blank-string/).

Update: Because `isBlank()` is a part of `StringUtils` and that's a separate library provided by Apache, You can import that library as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26773506/8244632).
 But if you don't want to use a separate library, you can also use `trim()` which removes spaces from a string's starting and ending point as:
 `" Name   "` -> `"Name"` 
 `" "` -> `""`
 So, what you can do with it, you can check its length and if it's 0, then it will return true as in case of `" "`. You can do it as:
`if (firebaseUser.getDisplayName() == null || firebaseUser.getDisplayName().trim().length() == 0){`

Comment: there is no method as isBlank() showing but isEmpty() is showing instead

Comment: Ah, Because it's a part of `StringUtils` and you've to use import it as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26773506/8244632). This is a separate lightweight library and although, it will provide many extra features but if you don't want to use a library, you can also use trim() which removes space from starting and ending of a string. Use it as `firebaseUser.getDisplayName().trim().length() == 0`. I'll also update this answer as well.

Comment: Hey @AmitGhosh try now. I've updated it.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Thanks for answering it worked for me

Comment: forgive me considering a newbie

Comment: @AmitGhosh I'm glad it helped. And there's nothing you should be forgiven for, everyone was a newbie once. You can personally message me if you don't get answer of something, I'll try to help.